# Python read Json into DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas

Lets say I have the json data with following:

```
 [
    {
        "cust_Name": [
            "Nia Bernard",
            "Nicole",
            "Katelin"
        ],
        "cust_Rate": [
            "1.0 out of 5 stars",
            "4.0 out of 5 stars",
            "5.0 out of 5 stars"
        ],
        "date_comment": [
            "Reviewed in the United States on January 10, 2019",
            "Reviewed in the United States on December 18, 2018",
            "Reviewed in the United States on August 14, 2017"
        ]
    }
]
```

How can I read this json format into data frame with the following output:

```
cust_Name      cust_Rate            date_comment
Nia Bernard    1.0 out of 5 stars   Reviewed in the United States on January 10, 2019
Nicole         4.0 out of 5 stars   Reviewed in the United States on December 18, 2018
Katelin        5.0 out of 5 stars   Reviewed in the United States on August 14, 2017
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read our [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get a better understanding about how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Have you read the documentation? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html

Comment: Your `json` data is not correctly formatted. If you remove the `[]` around it, you can simply use `pandas.read_json(<path_to_file>)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
data=[
    {
        "cust_Name": [
            "Nia Bernard",
            "Nicole",
            "Katelin"
        ],
        "cust_Rate": [
            "1.0 out of 5 stars",
            "4.0 out of 5 stars",
            "5.0 out of 5 stars"
        ],
        "date_comment": [
            "Reviewed in the United States on January 10, 2019",
            "Reviewed in the United States on December 18, 2018",
            "Reviewed in the United States on August 14, 2017"
        ]
    }
]
```

Now just create dataframe just by using `Dataframe()` method in `pandas`:-

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame(data[0])
```

Now if you print `df` you will get your expected output:-

```
cust_Name           cust_Rate             date_comment
0   Nia Bernard     1.0 out of 5 stars    Reviewed in the United States on January 10, 2019
1   Nicole          4.0 out of 5 stars    Reviewed in the United States on December 18, ...
2   Katelin         5.0 out of 5 stars    Reviewed in the United States on August 14, 2017
```

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a cleaner way with the attribute 'orient', but here is one way:

```
df_in = pd.read_json('your_file.json')
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=df_in.columns)
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df_in[col].values[0]
    
print(df)
```